# BibTex not working

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I am trying to use BibTeX for references. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{cite}

\title{Draft Project Laser Bubbles}
\author{PTB} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\abstract{
Optofluidics
}

\section{Theory}

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}{}

\end{document}
```

And `mybib.bib` in the same folder:

```
@article{Nobody06,
  author = "Nobody Jr",
  title = "My Article",
  year = "2006"
}

@article{mrx05,  
author = "Mr. X", 
Title = {Something Great}, 
publisher = "nob" # "ody"}, 
YEAR = 2005, 
}
```

Error message:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
> The top-level auxiliary file: Project-PTB-Draft.aux
> The style file: plain.bst
> Database file #1: mybib.bib
> Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Nobody06"
> (There was 1 warning)

I have tried `latex bibtex latex latex` (it is my Quick Build at the moment). Any ideas? :)

First problem found: mybib.bib was in the wrong folder. *facepalm*. Put it in the right folder and it still doesn't work. The current error message:

Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: Project-PTB-Draft.aux The style file: plain.bst Database file #1: mybib.bib You're missing an entry type---line 1 of file mybib.bib : @ :

Process exited normally

EDIT:

I fixed it! I deleted the old .bib file and made a new one in texmaker. Then it worked!

I guess an encoding problem or something :)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Hi! Are you calling `bibtex mybib` or `bibtex mytexfile`? Because the first way doesn't work, you have to go the second way.

Comment: When I do the standard calls (see @tohecz) the MWE compiles without any errors.

Comment: For me the code above compiles without problems (in PDFLaTeX).

Comment: Make sure that you actually saved your bib. And I would suggest to give the bib a more specific name e.g. petter-2013, so that you can be sure that you are not a editing a copy with the same name in some other place.

Comment: @Guido I actually start to doubt that this is the problem. Because the log output from `bibtex` shows that the call is correct. I more think that PetterTB has a typo his the real document somewhere (for instance mismatched upper/lowercase)

Comment: There is an unbalanced brace `}` in the publisher of the second item, the bibliography command should be just `\bibliography{mybib}` without the extra `{}`.  Otherwise the posted code compiles fine, just that bibtex warns "Warning--empty journal in Nobody06".

Comment: I feel stupid, the mybib.bib was in another folder *facepalm*. When I moved it to the correct folder, it still doesn't work, tho. The error message changes:

Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: Project-PTB-Draft.aux The style file: plain.bst Database file #1: mybib.bib You're missing an entry type---line 1 of file mybib.bib : @ :

Process exited normally

I do have @article in the first line *confused*

Comment: I use the compilation buttons in tex maker.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Fixed that (removed the second item and the braces). Still the same error message. The extra braces were included in the example at the bibtex site.

Comment: Have you tried compiling from the command line instead of from tex maker?  Another possibility is that you have `mybib.bib` several places on the system and the wrong file is being picked up.

Answer (score 6):

As tohecz said you have to use the following commands to compile your file:

```
latex texfile
bibtex texfile
latex texfile
latex texfile
pdflatex texfile
```

where `texfile` is your file with LaTeX code. If I run your files with these commands it compiles perfectly.

Comment: This clearly does not answer the question if you analyze it carefully ;)